# Should I reinstall Nero after Hardware is changed?

Tags: windows-xp, reinstall, dvd-burning, nero

- My XP box has an old BenQ CD Writer(the drive itself is pretty capricious)
- I recently purchased an ASUS DVD Writer for another box
- To test the DVD functionality, I installed the DVD drivers etc on the old XP box (had disconnected the BenQ drive at the time)
- Having moved the DVD Writer to the new box (which is not yet ready owing to HDD issues), I'm loath to move the new drive back into the old box to write UBCD
- Nero detects the BenQ drive as an ATAPI CD Writer and the software seems to follow the correct flow.

Is the change in hardware transparent to Nero? Could this change cause any irrecoverable damage to the drive?

Will Nero provide the correct signals to the CD Writer?

Should I reinstall Nero to avoid the risk of burning coasters (at the least)?

Answer (score 1):

A reinstall is not needed, I'd probably remove the BenQ DVD drivers and let Windows grab the correct drivers

---

Head over to Device Manager, remove the existing DVD drives and reboot.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to identify the DVD drivers please?

Comment: How did you `I installed the DVD drivers etc on the old XP box` ? I'd probably ask you to head over to device manager, remove the existing DVD drives and reboot.